# Tournament with the property $S_k$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm wondering what's the matter with this property on oriented graphs :

$$ T= (V(T),E(T)) \text{ has prop } S_k \text{ if for any k vertices } v_1, \cdots, v_k \in V(T) \\ \text{ there exist a vertex } u \in V(T) \text{ such that } uv_1, uv_2, \cdots, uv_k \in E(T) $$

I think that $S_1$ is the necessary and sufficient condition for having a connected graph (is this even true? I don't know if we consider the direction of the edges), but what about this property for any k ? what is it saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_k$ says that every $k$ vertices have a common (direct) ancestor (predecessor may be the better, or more familiar term).

This does not say that the graph is connected for $k=1$.

For $k=1$ (and $T$ finite!) it *does* say that there is a directed cycle. The disjoint union of two directed cycles however satisfies $S_1$ but is not connected.

For $k>1$ and $T$ finite it does imply that the underlying simple graph is connected, but $T$ still does not need to be strongly connected.

For infinite graphs all bets are off: there need not even be cycles.

EDIT: above is for general digraphs (overlooking the fact that the question title clearly states tournaments).

In a tournament you can show that property $S_k$ implies minimum in-degree $k$ (provided $k$ is smaller than the size of the tournament). You can prove this as follows:

Suppose a vertex $v$ has in-degree $l<k$. Let $v_1u,\ldots,v_lu$ be the $l$ in-edges of $u$. Let $v_{l+1},\ldots,v_{k-1}$ other vertices (possibly zero if $l=k-1$), different from $u$, and all $v_i$ different from each other. By definition $u,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{k-1}$ have a common predecessor $w$ that must be different from all $v_i$ and therefore is another in-edge for $u$. Contradiction.

Comment: what's an ancestor please. I m only studying finite graphs

Comment: In a directed graph $u$ is a direct ancestor of $v$ if there is a directed edge $uv$. I only mention finiteness, because if you want to prove that there is a directed cycle, this finiteness is explicitly required.

Comment: I'm also familiar with to notion of degre of a vertex. Does S_k imply that every vertex is of at least degree k?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you have a graph $T$ satisfying $S_2$, you can add four new vertices: $u$, $v$, $w$, $x$, such that $u$, $v$ and $w$ point to every other vertex, and only $u$ points to $x$. The new graph satisfies $S_2$ again, but $x$ has in-degree $1$ and outdegree $0$. This does require that you allow allow both edge $xy$ and directed edge $yx$ at the same time in your graph.

Comment: is xy \neq yx ? and is it possible that in a tournament you have both xy and yx? (both direction). Because if you don't, I'm not able to create an example $S_2$.
I'm not sure to fully understand your example. Is it possible to ask for a drawing ?

Comment: I mentioned that the example required edges in both directions. In a tournament that is not the case, by definition. This was just an example I could think up quickly. Will think again about the case of a tournament.

Comment: In fact the entire answer fails for tournaments. Sorry I overlooked that. A tournament cannot be the disjoint union of cycles. No more time right now, I will think about this again tomorrow. Better unaccept the answer for now.

Comment: No problem, waiting for your edit :)

Comment: Your intuition about the degree was correct. Answer has been edited to reflect that.

Comment: It makes sens. I m sorry, that s also the way I asked the question that was confusing, i m still learning the basics. Anyways, thank you for the help!